# Finding dynamic text using selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a webpage that dynamically places a text in a span. It is something like:

```
<table id=table_1>
  <td>
    <span> $available/$total <span><label id=label_1>Servers available</label>
  </td>
</table>
```

The only thing i know is that either "x/y Servers available" or "No Servers Available" would be displayed on the webpage.  Please let me know how can I get this `x` and `y`.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="refresh_div" >
      <table id="Server_status_table" >
      <!-- -----------For Server Status box header ---------------->
        <tr>                            
          <% 
            int num=Integer.parseInt(request.getAttribute("availWorkerCount").toString());
            int tot=Integer.parseInt(request.getAttribute("totalWorkerCount").toString());
            int avg = 0;
            if(tot!=0 && num>0){
              avg=num*100/tot;
            }
            pageContext.setAttribute("total", tot);
          %>

          <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${ total eq 0 }">
              <!-- -----------For showing how many servers are available now---------------->
              <td> 
                <label id="Avaibility_l" style="font-size: 120%;">Availability</label>
              </td>
              <td>
                <span>No server available</span>
              </td>
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>

              <!-- -----------For showing how many servers are available now---------------->
              <td> 
                <label id="Avaibility_l" style="font-size: 120%;">Availability</label>
                <br/> &nbsp 
              </td>
              <td >
                <!-- -----------For showing the availability bar---------------->

                <div id="progress" class="progress">
                  <div id="bar" class="bar" style="width:<%=avg %>%;"></div>
                </div>

                <!-- -----------For showing the availability progress detail message---------------->
                <span>
                  ${availWorkerCount} / ${totalWorkerCount}<label id="Progress_message_l"> occupied</label>
                </span>
              </td>
            </c:otherwise>
          </c:choose>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <!-- -----------For showing the approximate Queue Wait time ---------------->
          <td>
            <label id="Queue_wait_time_l" style="font-size: 120%;">Queue waiting time</label>
          </td>

          <!-- -----------For showing the approximate wait time detail message---------------->
          <td >
            <label id="Wait_time _message_1stpart_l" >Approximately</label>
            ${queueWaitingTime}
          </td>

        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I need  `${availWorkerCount}` , `${totalWorkerCount}` and `${queueWaitingTime}`

Comment: If x and y are parameters passed from a form then you can use request.getParameter(),if its present in session then you can use sess.getAttribute().Your question is incomplete.Give more details

Comment: They are passed using java-script variables

Comment: show the code how they are passed

Answer (score 0):

With WebDriver you're picking text off from the page after it has finished loading. Thus getting this kind of "dynamic" text won't be a problem. Your example is only dynamic on the server side, in the client side the text from these variables would be static content and just as easy to grab from the page as any other text.

I suggest you put an `id` attribute to the `<span>` you're looking for, then it's super simple to get its contents with Selenium.

For example:

```
<span id="myStuff">foobar</span>
```

And fetch it with:

```
String contentsOfMySpan = driver.findElement(By.id("myStuff")).getText();
```

*** EDIT ***

Since you can't change original code, here's the hard way to do it:

```
By qwt = By.xpath("//label[@id = 'Wait_time _message_1stpart_l']/parent::td/text()[2]");
By wc = By.xpath("//label[@id = 'Progress_message_l']/parent::span/text()[1]");

String queueWaitingTime = driver.findElement(qwt).getText();
String[] workerCounts = driver.findElement(wc).getText().split(" / ");
String availWorkerCount = workerCounts[0];
String totalWorkerCount = workerCounts[1];
```

Comment: Thanks. But i can't do changes in the original code as it is a client code

Comment: $available/$total - they are tags right when the html will be created they will get evaluated and the value will be printed. You want that value right?

Comment: @shruti: Ok, edited answer to reflect how to pick them up from unchanged source.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea. Please follow the below steps might work for you, this answer is from the HTML prospective. I not sure what you mean by

```
I need ${availWorkerCount} , ${totalWorkerCount} and ${queueWaitingTime}
```

Full example code after the steps. Just to mention, I have not ran this code.

1.Search the Element label by text

```
label[contains(.,'Servers available')]
```

you can add id check with it also like

```
label[contains(@id,'label_1') and contains(.,'Servers available')]
```

2.get the label and then get the parallel element span. Span should have the value

CODE :

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("label[contains(@id,'label_1') and contains(.,'Servers available')]");
for(// now loop over the elements)
{
  WebElement elem = elements.get(0);
  List<WebElement> spanelems = elem.findElements(By.xpath("../span"));
  spanelems.get(0).getText() // this should give you the data under the span
}
```